# How to implement custom error handling with retroift2

Tags: java, error-handling, retrofit, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

I calling to the api with the basic retrofit `Call` object:

```
public interface dataApi {
    @GET("animal/cats")
    Call<AllAnimals> getAllData(
            @Query("api_key") String apiKey
    );
}
```

And I can get the response inside my view model like this:

```
  call.enqueue(new Callback<AllAnimals>() {

      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<AllAnimals> call, Response<AllAnimals> response) {
          animals.setValue(response.body());
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<AllAnimals> call, Throwable t) {
          Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);

      }
  });
```

Nothing speical here.

I've several problem with this approach

**FIRST** - if I give the wrong api key for example, the response should give me a response with the code of the problem, instead I just get null body.

**SECOND** I am planning to have more api calls, and it's a huge code duplication to handle errors every call I wrote.

How can I implement custom error handling for this situation, that will be apply to other calls too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [okhttp interceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/) and define yourself ResponseBody converter to fix your problem.

- First,intercept you interested request and response;
- Second,check the response,if response is failed then modify the response body to empty。

**define a simple interceptor**

```
Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        String url = request.url().toString();
        System.out.println(request.url());
        okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        if (!response.isSuccessful() && url.contains("animal/cats")) {
            // request failed begin to modify response body
            response = response.newBuilder()
                .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), new byte[] {}))
                .build();
        }

        return response;
    }
};
```

**define self ResponseBody converter**

most code from [com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) we just add two lines:

```
final class JacksonResponseBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
    private final ObjectReader adapter;

    JacksonResponseBodyConverter(ObjectReader adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        try {
            if (value.contentLength() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return adapter.readValue(value.charStream());
        } finally {
            value.close();
        }
    }
}
```

the below code is added：

```
if (value.contentLength() == 0) {
    return null;
}
```